# NodeJs Separate Dev and Prod Environment Variables

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables, backend, production-environment

I have a nodejs server and in my service files, I am getting the url for the requests from the config.json file I created shown below. The issue is I want to use a different variable url for dev and different for production. In other words the URL should run prod url from config.json file when in prod and dev url from config.json when running in dev environment. I am new to environment variables in nodejs so any help would be appreciated.

one of my service.js files is:

```
const config = require('../config');



async function getOrderLineItems(data) {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: config.cloverApiUrl ,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + data.token,
      ContentType: 'application/json'
    },
  };
  const response = await got(options);
  return response.body;
}
```

my config.json file is:

```
{
    "connectionString": "connectionString",
    "secret": "secret",
    "cloverApiUrl": "cloverApiUrl",
    "clientSecret": "clientSecret",
    "keyUrl": "keyUrl",
    "tokenUrl": "tokenUrl"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Either install config package.

The project directory will look like,

config

- default.json

https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

2. Else create a .env file in the project directory then access it through process.en.variable_name

Answer (score 0):

You can have two config files one for production and one for development and using `process.env.NODE_ENV` will return the current environment and with a simple condition, you can decide which file you can require(if this could be another object with the env as the key and the require statement as the value)

```js
let config;
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
 config = require('path/to/config.prod.json');
}else if....

//or something like this
const config = require('config.json')[process.env.NODE_ENV]
//where config is something like this

module.export = {
 'production':{...},
 'development':{...}
}
```

and you can add NODE_ENV=... to your script to decide the env

```
"server": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon index.js",
```